# Thread and Queue interconnection in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is a code:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class DownloadWorker(Thread):
   def __init__(self, queue):
       Thread.__init__(self)
       self.queue = queue

   def run(self):
        while True: 
           print(self.queue.get())
           self.queue.task_done()

for x in range(8):
       worker = DownloadWorker(queue)
       worker.daemon = True
       worker.start()          
for i in range(10):
       queue.put(i)
queue.join()
```

I'm looking for a book or some good articles for beginners that could tidy up my understanding of the code:

1. Why I need to initiate While loop in the Thread?
2. How Queue manage to kill early initiated Threads when there is: a) an empty queue (I guess this done by queue.join()) b) a queue was completed.
3. What would happen when in Thread instead of "print(self.queue.get())" I would put more data to queue "queue.put()"?

I read help and few articles but I feel unsure about interconnection of Thread and Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(self.queue.get())` prints everything that is in the queue. You need a while loop because you need to keep listening to the elements in the queue.
A `queue.put()` is used as the sending end of the queue. a process can use `queue.put()` to pass data to another process which then reads the data with `queue.get()`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

def f(q):
    diff_dict = {'a':'b'}
    q.put(diff_dict)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())   # prints {'a':'b'}
    p.join()
```

In the example, function `f` puts items in the queue and main function listens to the queue by `q.get()`